# How to change the vis timeline language?

Tags: angular-cli, momentjs, npm-install, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I'm a newbie with Angular and node.js.
I'm currently working on a project with a timeline from visjs timeline.
In documentation, I've found this:
*"For localization, Timeline depends largely on the localization of moment.js. Locales are not included in vis.js by default. Moment.js offers a bundle named "moment-with-locales.min.js" for this and there are various alternative ways to load locales."*
But it doesn't work for me and I'm not sure if I'm right on installation.

I installed these npm packages (package.json refs): 
[image: two muppets]

I set the option to "fr"like below:

```
    this.options = {
    orientation: 'top',
    stack: false,
    height: this.fullSize ? '80vh' : '100vh',
    showTooltips: true,
    groupOrder: "id",
    locale:"fr",      
    moveable: this.fullSize,
    zoomable: this.fullSize,
    start : start,
    end: end
    }
```

The expected is to see the timeline in french, but it stills in English.

May someone can help?

Thanks!